# Is there an way to concat words from given word sets into grammatical sentence?

Tags: nlp, nltk, combinatorics

I want to build sentence of fixed length 
S = w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 ..... wN.
N is already known to me. I have a set of words for each word position wi where i = 1 to N. I have to pick one word from each wi to construct a sentence S. S must be grammatically correct; and I don't want to check the meaning of sentence S. Is there any way to achieve this using NLTK's toolkit or any other NLP toolkit?

I can construct sentences from the given word list using the DFS algorithm and then check whether each sentence is grammatically correct or not. But the set size for each word is large (scale of 10^3), so it takes too much time to construct a sentence for even three word sentences.

> Suppose, I want to build three word sentence S = w1 w2 w3.
>
> w1 = {I, you, we, he, she,...},
>   w2 = {eat, drink, read, who,
>   how,...},
>   w3 = {banana, tea, music,... }
>
> Valid sentences (Grammatically Correct):
>
> - I eat banana.
> - I drink tea.
> - I eat music.
> - I drink banana.
> - I read banana and so on.
>
> Invalid Sentences (Grammatically Incorrect):
>
> - I who banana.
> - I how book.

Comment: When you say 10^3 takes too long, do you mean it takes too long to check every option (meaning 10^3^N where N is the number of words used in the sentence)? Because normally iterating through 1000 things isn't too difficult. 10^3^3 = 1 billion is alot to check through though.

Comment: Also, are you trying to build 1 sentence that is grammatically correct, or all possible grammatically correct sentences, or something else?

Comment: The trivial solution to your three-word problem is to exclude words which are not verbs (who, how) from the second list.

Comment: I want to generate all possible grammatically correct sentences. For three word sentence, suppose I choose w1 = I then by following English grammar we can not put w2 = is but I choose w1 = he then we can put w2 = is. I don't want to generate all sentences and then check how many of them are grammatically correct. I want to pick words based on previously chosen words that gives grammatically correct sentence. Usually, Number of words in a sentence N <= 10.